# Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.28 but the client library is 5.6.22/ Mac OS X/10.9.5

Tags: mysql, sql-server

After updating my MAC OS X to 10.9.5 version, 
I was getting the following error 
when trying to connect to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_dat.
(I am using NetBeans IDE):

[image]

The SQL Server is running:

[image]

The reason for connection problem was

```
 Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.28
 but the client library  is 5.6.22.
```

I have looked  at the reasons and possible solutions. I did the following steps:

```
Zoulfias-iMac:~ zoulfiahall$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
5.6.22
Zoulfias-iMac:~ zoulfiahall$ cd zhall/Myapp
Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$ gem install mysql2 
-- --with-mysql-  config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysql_config
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.17.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: 
'--with-mysql-  config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysql_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.17
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.17
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.17
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$
```

The problem now is that  somehow it is needed to pass the option to bundler, to do that you can use    bundler config.

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysql_config
```

Unfortunately, get the same error message:

```
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.28 
but the client library     is 5.6.22.
/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/
mysql2.rb:8:in `   require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/
lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-  1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-  1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/
ruby-head@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-  1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
 /Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/Users/zoulfiahall/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/
gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/zoulfiahall/zhall/Myapp/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/zoulfiahall/zhall/Myapp/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
Click here to rerun the task with tracing enabled
```

I check whether I can start the server:

```
  Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$ mysql.server start
  Starting MySQL
  SUCCESS! 
  Zoulfias-iMac:Myapp zoulfiahall$ mysql -uroot
  Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
  Your MySQL connection id is 32
  Server version: 5.6.22 Homebrew

 Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
  owners.

  Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql> SELECT version();
   +-----------+
   | version() |
   +-----------+
   | 5.6.22    |
   +-----------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help will be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: As the error says, you're getting access denied for those credentials.

Comment: I know what error is, how do I sort it out?

Comment: ...use the correct credentials.

Comment: They are the correct credentials. I didn't use any other credentials.

Comment: Is `root` really the mysql account you're using?

Comment: Yes.It is.I need to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the problems were related to mysql connector. I needed to update it. I use NetBeans IDE. I just replaced an old mysql driver with the new one. I restarted my MySQL server. It worked. 
Maybe someone will find my answer helpful.